# Flutter AppBar Icon is not responsive on all screens

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-appbar

i Have two icons on my appbar on clicking save save  icon dissappers and approve icon will pop it works fine but by app bar icon on larger screen cut according to below image. here is mycode

```
appBar: PreferredSize(
      preferredSize:  Size.fromHeight(70.0),
      child: AppBar(
      elevation: 10,
      automaticallyImplyLeading: false,
      backgroundColor: Colors.red,
        title:  Text('Edit',style:
              TextStyle(fontSize: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width*0.1),
        ),

        actions: <Widget>[
          isVisibile
              ?  Container(
            height: 50,
                width: 50,
                child: Padding(
                  padding:  EdgeInsets.only(right:MediaQuery.of(context).size.width*0.3),
                  child: IconButton(
                        icon:  Icon(
                            Icons.save,
                            color: Colors.white,
                            size: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width*0.1,
                          ),

                        onPressed: () {
                          
                        },
                      ),
                ),
              )

              : Container(),
          isInvisible
              ? Padding(
                padding: EdgeInsets.only(right:MediaQuery.of(context).size.width*0.05,bottom: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height*0.05),
                child: IconButton(
                    icon: Icon(
                      Icons.done,
                      color: Colors.white,
                      size: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width*0.1,
                    ),
                    onPressed: () async {
                      // approve
                    },
                  ),
              )
              : Container(),
        ],
      //),
      ),
    ),
```

here is my app bar on large screens
[image]
here is my image on small screen
[image]

so how can i make icons responsive thanks

Answer (score 2):

Put your AppBar widget as a child of `Container` and set margin to `EdgeInset.all(4)`. This should work.

Try Following code :

```
appBar: PreferredSize(
      preferredSize:  Size.fromHeight(70.0),
      child: Container(
              padding: EdgeInset.all(4), // you can change this value to 8 
            child:AppBar(
            ...
```

Comment: Jay Dangar it works there is error container margin i rectify it padding thanks